# create labels on a form based on entries in datagridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, forms, datagridview, label

I have a form with a datagridview containing entries for an invoice.  I have created a separate form that will contain the entries from the datagridview in labels.  Unfortunately, I am having trouble finding out how to generate a table of labels with each label holding the value of the corresponding entry in the datagridview.  I am wondering if it is possible to do this with a for next loop based on the number of rows in the datagridview.  Thanks in advance for any guidance in this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim lbl As New Label
With lbl
   .Text = txtCaption    ' value you want it to display from dgv.dr
   .Top = 
   .Left = 
   .Name =
   .Size =
End With
```

I dont know what you mean by a table of labels, so lets say you want to add them to a panel there just for them:

```
pnlLabels.Controls.Add(lbl)
```

Make that a Sub and call it from the loop processing the rows in the datagridview, passing the relevant value for its caption.  Something like this:

```
CreateLabel(ndx as Integer, txtCaption as String)
```

You will need an index or counter of how many made so that some properties like .Top can be offset accordingly.

EDIT

I have no idea what your dgv or data etc looks like, but your loop would be SOMETHING like this:

```
pnlLabels.Controls.Clear             ' might want to remove any old ones

Dim Caption as String = ""
Dim ndx As Integer = 0
For Each dr As DataGridViewRow in dgv.rows
     Caption = dr.Cells(X)        ' or where the data is

     CreateLabel(ndx, Caption)
     ndx += 1
Next
```

Comment: I'm brand new here, so I hope I am responding correctly.  I have tried something like this but was having trouble using it in a for next loop.  I thought that I could use a loop to gather the entries in each row of the datagridview.  I will try to reconstruct the code and present it here for further help.  Thank you Plutonix!

Comment: Thank you for the loop code outline.  I'll try it and let you know how it works.  I was thinking of using a for each instead of for next.  Hopefully that will make the difference.  Thanks again!

Comment: To add some additional information.  The datagridview is 6 columns wide and an undetermined number of rows.  So, I'm trying to encapsulate each cell in the same layout as the datagridview on an invoice form.  Other information on the form shows up nicely, but for some reason I keep running into problems when trying to add the information in each cell of the datagridview.  I am attempting to provide the label with this info by doing
  
     lbl.text = Main.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).value 
repeating this line of code for each column and changing the value inside .Cells().

Comment: I am also using GroupBoxInvoiceInvoice.Controls.Add(lbl) at the end of the loop to place the lbl on the form inside the GroupBox.  Other criteria like lbl.Location are being provided within the loop also.

Comment: if the labels are ever rebuilt (new captions, thus new label controls) you really want to add them to a dedicated control (if possible), so you can remove them easily, without looping thru every single control on the form trying to find your special lablels.  If you have to do that, use the TAG or special namining to find them.  `lbl.text = Main.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).value` SHOULD work without actually building controls but that is NOT what the org question asked.  Shouldnt it be `Cells(0).Text` though?  DONT build new controls if you dont have to....

Comment: Thank you, Plutonix.  I've tried to click on the vote up to show my appreciation for your help, but for some reason it's not showing.